# javascript Slider not working , it wont slide

Tags: javascript, slider, swiper.js

```
var swiper = new Swiper(".home-slider", {
    loop:true,
    navigation: {
      nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
      prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
    },
});
```

tried to add swiper.js slider , it wont slide, here is the back-end code.

Comment: does it give you a error?

Comment: Check the browser's console tab in the web inspector to see if there is any obvious JavaScript errors.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.